# Download Image from azure blob storage and download it

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services

I am working with Xamarin forms and I've stored an image in Azure blob storage which I'd like to download on page load and put into an image view, as of now I have this code:

```
using(var fileStream = imageStore.GetStream())
{
     blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(fileStream);
}
```

This code should download the image into a file stream (Please let me know if I'm wrong) but then I need to get the image out of that file stream and set it as the image view source, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: ImageSource.FromStream()

Comment: @Jason i'm figuring you mean like this: image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(fileStream); in which case i get that it can't convert system.io.stream to system.func<system.io.stream>

Comment: google it, there are lots of examples

Answer (score 4):

You can directly convert the stream to an `Image.Source` via the static method `ImageSource.FromStream`:

```
using (var fileStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(fileStream);
    image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => fileStream);
}
```

Note: `DownloadToStreamAsync` returns a `Task`, so `await` it...

Comment: i've tried this but it gives me: can't convert system.io.stream to system.func<system.io.stream>

Comment: @AppleGeek typo as I was doing it from the top of the head, it should be a func....

Comment: the image won't pop up and in the output window it says: ImageLoaderSourceHandler: Image data was invalid: Xamarin.Forms.StreamImageSource

Comment: @AppleGeek, before you use the stream to get the image source (`(...)FromStream(() => fileStream)`), try to set it's position to zero: `fileStream.Position = 0;`.

Comment: @AppleGeek are you sure there is a valid image stored on Azure? Try to convert bytes array to Base64String and test it on an online tool. Sushi's answer should work

Comment: Also check the console output of the mobile device to insure that you can not failing due to a secure channel issue (i.e. Are you using SSL and are you using the "native" client handlers in each mobile application project and not Mono's managed handler.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza it should be valid its a png